# Spark Scala - Create an object with element from my dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For a Scala Project I am working on, I had to create a class `Table` as below :

```
class Table(PbddName : String , PTableName: String, POutputFilename: String="", PFilteringFlag: Boolean=true) {
  var bddName : String = PbddName
  var TableName: String = PTableName
  var OutputFilename: String = POutputFilename
  var FilteringFlag: Boolean =PFilteringFlag
}
```

To create a Table, I use this code in a `Scala object` :

```
        val randomName = new Table(bddName, blablaTableName, blablaOutputFilename,blablaFilteringFlag)
        list_tables+=randomName
```

I also add it to `list_Tables` that obviously list all the tables.

But as I have a lot of "Tables" to create, I made a csv where each line contains the needed values to create a Table (matching the values of the class). I loaded my CSV file in a DataFrame called `empDF` that matches this :

```
|bdd_name|    table_name|     file_name|filtering_flag|
+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|    bdd1|name1tablename| name1Filename|          true|
|    bdd2|name2tablename| name2Filename|          true|
|    bdd3|name3tablename| name3Filename|         false|
|    bdd4|name4tablename| name4Filename|          true|
+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I would like to know how to automate the creation of my "Tables" elements ?(and add the created table to my `list_Tables`). I am not sure, but I think I might have to browse my dataframe somehow to create the element at each line that is readden.

Also, each `val` name (here randomName) must be different, but can be random.

If you have any idea, or any clue on how I could do this, that would help me a lot.

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to do what I wanted :

```
for (row <- empDF.rdd.collect) {
  var bddname = row.mkString(",").split(",")(0)
  var tablename = row.mkString(",").split(",")(1)
  var Outputfilename = row.mkString(",").split(",")(2)
  var filteringflag = row.mkString(",").split(",")(3)



  val nomtable =new Table(bddname, tablename, Outpufilename, filteringflag, tablename)
  list_tables +=nomtable
}
```

I actually don't need a different name for all the tables so this solution works for me at this point.
The only thing is, I counldn't process the same method for both `String` and `Boolean` so I had to change all my elements from my `Table` class to String.